# Katare DSL - can't read a .prn file in the feature file, it throws the error "gnoring dynamic expression, did not evaluate to list"

Tags: testing, karate, file-read

I have problems reading a .prn file (cvs saved as .prn).
it throws me the error

> 12:47:00.930 [main] WARN  com.intuit.karate - ignoring dynamic expression, did not evaluate to list: read('Requests/file.prn') - [type: INPUT_STREAM, value: java.io.FileInputStream@30c31dd7]

But if i change the extension to a .cvs it's works great.
There exist a way to read this .prn file with karate-dsl to evaluate as list?

> ```
> Feature: scenario outline using a table from a prn file
>   ....
>   Background: 
>   *print ('Hello :)')
>   ....
>   Scenario Outline: ....
>   ...
>   Examples:
>   | read('Requests/file.prn') |
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation [dynamic scenario outline](https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline) in karate only supports JSON array and CSV formats.

you have to write your own Java/Javascript function to convert your PRN file into JSON Array, then it can be passed via examples.